# 404 redirection to multiple error page htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have two URLs

```
/web/20110606105658/
/about-us/AwardDetails.aspx?AWDID=1
```

i have to set different 404 error page for URL in htaccess

ex. 
    `/web/20110606105658/` should go to `www.google.com` 
    `/about-us/AwardDetails.aspx?AWDID=1` should go to `www.yahoo.com`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `mod_rewrite` rules for this 404 handling:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^web/20110606105658/?$ http://www.google.com/ [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^AWDID=1$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^about-us/AwardDetails\.aspx$ http://www.yahoo.com/ [L,NC,R=301]
```